# Issue with accents from Python source code

Tags: accents, python

I am inserting a Python source code in a LaTeX document using the `fancyvrb` package. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[francais]{babel} 

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\VerbatimInput[frame=single, numbers=left, numbersep=2pt]{test.py}

\end{document}
```

test.py is

```
valeur = input('Veuillez entrer une valeur numérique : ')

# Il s'agit d'un texte à la fois très accentué et très court.
```

The issue is that upon compilation I obtain the following.

[image]

How can I get the accents right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python source code is encoded in UTF-8, not latin1. This can be managed by changing the input encoding via `\inputencoding`.

Also the `babel`'s `frenchb.ldf` interferes. This can be circumvented by setting a different language.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8,latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\inputencoding{utf8}
\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
\VerbatimInput[frame=single, numbers=left, numbersep=2pt]{test.py}
\end{otherlanguage*}
\inputencoding{latin1}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

`utf8` must be loaded in the preamble once, therefore the two encoding options for `inputenc`. Also `\inputencoding{utf8}` contains global assignments, thus it cannot be limited by a group unlike the other encodings.