# Issue with special characters in Python code

Tags: symbols, verbatim, python

I am trying to insert a Python code into a LaTeX document. The Python code (an example) is the following and contains many special characters (>, <, °):

```
valeur = input('Veuillez entrer une valeur numérique ° : ')

if '.' in valeur
    print('Hourra')

        if x<0 or x>10:
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[francais]{babel} 

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\inputencoding{utf8}
\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
\VerbatimInput[frame=single, numbers=left, numbersep=2pt]{test.py}
\end{otherlanguage*}
\inputencoding{latin1}

\end{document}
```

Because of the special characters, I am getting this error:

[image]

How can I fix it?

This question is closely related to the post [Issue with accents from Python source code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265976/issue-with-accents-from-python-source-code) but it is no duplicate since I was dealing with accents and now I am seemingly dealing with mathematical symbols used outside math mode...

The answer to [Issue with accents from Python source code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265976/issue-with-accents-from-python-source-code) does not solve my current problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue with accents from Python source code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265976/issue-with-accents-from-python-source-code)

Comment: It is not a duplicate since the problem is different.

Comment: In Issue with accents from Python source code, the problem was with the accents. Here, it is with math symbols used outside math mode...

Comment: Ok, I was missinterpretead. You should modify your MWE to use only math character that causes the failure without the accent

Comment: It's my interpretation of MWE perhaps. Everything that can be removed because not causing the failure should be removed

Comment: Why don't you use the `listings` package which is supposed to do the job of including code lines in a LaTeX document ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to declare that you want to use UTF-8. For the degree symbol you also need `textcomp`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8,latin1]{inputenc}  % last one is default
\usepackage[english,francais]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\inputencoding{utf8}
\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
\VerbatimInput[frame=single, numbers=left, numbersep=2pt]{test.py}
\end{otherlanguage*}
\inputencoding{latin1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why not using UTF-8 also for the other files?

Comment: It does not work with my LaTeX editor. I don't know why...

Comment: Did not know I could mix input encodings within a document. Great solution, but the listings package may be better for typesetting code than fancyvrb as listings can mark keywords and more.

Comment: out of curiosity, how would you disable the pretty-quoting for code blocks?

Comment: @NickT `\usepackage{upquote}`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use plain `verbatim` for code, use one of the specialized packages. I'm partial to `listings`, but there are many others; `minted` uses Python's `Pygments` to typeset code and is reported to be very flexible.

Comment: That is what I mentioned in a previous comment, there is packages for this kind of things